# Is this the fastest way and a new way to test special prime numbers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, primes

Sample code:

```
bool is_special_prime (int N) {
  QHash<int, int> o;
  struct A_functor
  {
    int operator()(unsigned int n) { return n >> __builtin_ctz(n);}
  }A;
  int k = A(N + 1);
  if(k == 1)
    return 0;
  o[k] = k;
  int t = (N - 5) >> 1;
  for(int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
      k = A(N + k);
      if(k == 1 || o.contains(k))
        return 0;
      o[k] = k;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Is this way can test numbers greater than the latest largest prime 2 ^ 57885161 − 1?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what the algorithm does, and why you think it might work as a primality test? Even so, there may not enough leading-edge number theorists here to verify your algorithm if it is correct and novel. Presumably, `N` is the exponent of a potential Mersenne prime (e.g. 57885161), not the prime number itself (which would be obviously be far too big for `int`).

Comment: It is correct and novel.This way is nothing to do with int,this is only sample code.

Comment: If you know it's correct and novel, why are you asking vague questions about it here rather than publishing your ground-breaking research? If not, then you'll need to ask a clearer question; the code is a bit hard to follow without knowing what the single-letter variables represent and what the bits of arithmetic are supposed to achieve.

Comment: I said it is correct and novel,but I'm not for sure so I ask.

Comment: @miket I would say try math.stackexchange.com, but you'd have to expand your answer a lot more with an explanation before asking a question there (SO accepts questions covering all ranges of experience, whereas math.stackexchange only allows quite high-level questions).

Comment: Thanks,I tried math.stackexchange.com,they give me -3.

Comment: You were told there to add more explanation, but instead re-posted your question here with even less information. That's simply unhelpful. Sorry, closing here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read about Lucas-Lehmer? It sounds like you have a bit more study to do before you're finding new and faster ways to test for primes. Try implementing Lucas-Lehmer with a bignum library first.

Your algorithm iterates up to N/2, so far from being quick, it's in fact extremely slow indeed (much slower than a prime seive). It also could never find a prime bigger than 2^32 or 2^64, which is quite a bit less than 2^57885161. Do you see why it's so slow? It can't return 1 until it's looped over value of i less than N/2.

I haven't checked whether your code accurately determines primes or not.

Comment: Yes I read about Lucas-Lehmer before. it iterates up to N/2,but only additions and right bit shift. You know Lucas-Lehmer needs large scale squre.

Comment: @miket But Lucas-Lehmer needs only `O(log N)` arithmetic operations. Even with a naive multiplication and division implementation it would blow `N/2` additions and shifts out of the water.

Comment: You bet if test 2 ^ 57885161 − 1  Lucas-Lehmer needs  3 years,if use fastest computer,the new only take less than 1 sec.

Comment: @miket That's because your test specifically rules out all numbers of the form `2^n - 1` as the very first step. So on those, it's of course fast. But it doesn't help in the least to determine whether such a number is prime. It rules out a few numbers of other special form very fast too, but in general it takes a looong time to finish. Trial division to the square root has lower algorithmic complexity on average.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `int` type which can hold numbers in the range `-2^31 to 2^31-1` on a 32 bit system. You cannot use it to test a number of the order you had mentioned

Comment: This is sample code not related to range,you know if test  numbers greater than the latest largest prime 2 ^ 57885161 − 1,you need something more.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this way can test numbers greater than the latest largest prime 2 ^ 57885161 − 1?

If you happen to use a platform where `int` is at least 57885162 bits wide then yes (assuming your algorithm is correct, which I didn't bother to check).

Now, let's be serious just a few seconds: with consumer-grade computers nowadays using at most 64 bits wide integers, you can see it's quite a long shot from that hypothetical platform...

You need to replace `int` with a BigNum library if you want to perform such calculations (and there will be other constraints along the way, too -- brace yourself).